# MKOverlay not resizing smoothly

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, mapkit, overlay

I have added a MKCircle as MKOverlay to my MKMapView. Also I added an UISlider to decide the radius of the circle. Unfortunately when using this it seems a bit "laggy", not smootly like I want it to be.

Example:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3077127/mkoverlayDelay.mov

This is my code:

```
- (void)addCircle
{
    // draw the radius circle for the marker
    double radius = 2000.0;
    MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:location radius:radius];
    [circle setTitle:@"background"];
    [mapView addOverlay:circle];

    MKCircle *circleLine = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:location radius:radius];
    [circleLine setTitle:@"line"];
    [mapView addOverlay:circleLine];
}

- (void)addCircleWithRadius:(double)radius
{
    MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:location radius:radius];
    [circle setTitle:@"background"];
    [mapView addOverlay:circle];

    MKCircle *circleLine = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:location radius:radius];
    [circleLine setTitle:@"line"];
    [mapView addOverlay:circleLine];
}

- (void)sliderChanged:(UISlider*)sender
{
    [mapView removeOverlays:[mapView overlays]];

    double radius = (sender.value * 100);

    [self addCircleWithRadius:radius];
}

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay{
    MKCircle *circle = overlay;
    MKCircleView *circleView = [[[MKCircleView alloc] initWithCircle:overlay] autorelease];

    if ([circle.title isEqualToString:@"background"])
    {
        circleView.fillColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x598DD3);
        circleView.alpha = 0.25;
    }
    else
    {
        circleView.strokeColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x5C8AC7);
        circleView.lineWidth = 2.0;
    }

    return circleView;
}
```

Does anybody have any suggestions on how I can smoothen this?

Best regards,
Paul Peelen

Comment: +1 for nicely documented question.  Is there any need to remove the overlay, why not just update it?

Comment: Thanks! I don't think there is any need.. but how can I update the overlay?

Comment: I'm not sure you can? I always thought the MapKit overlays were immutable, you can't modify them once created. This answer suggests the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171572/how-to-update-mkpolyline-mkpolylineview

Comment: Allright, thanks for the comment. Either way, I am looking for smoothening this... any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have tried your code and found a very easy way to make it smoother.

If you change the order of the calls in: `- (void)sliderChanged:(UISlider*)sender`

You can call `[self addCircleWithRadius:radius];`

before calling `[mapView removeOverlays:[mapView overlays]];`

Just make sure you dont remove the overlays you just added, only the old ones.

This will give you a smoother resizing, specially when the new circle is smaller than the old one.

For circles that are bigger you are probably better off using `NSOperations` to ensure the views are created faster, this will make it smoother.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good idea. I'll give it a try. Could you elaborate your suggestion with NSOperations?

Comment: Im glad you like the idea, in regards to bigger circles I would point you to the [Breadcrumb](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Breadcrumb/Introduction/Intro.html) example.

Comment: Looking for an `NSOperation` tutorial I came by [this one](http://icodeblog.com/2010/03/04/iphone-coding-turbo-charging-your-apps-with-nsoperation/), it is very complete and should help you create the `MKCircle` objects faster. Just remember you can only update the user interface from the main run loop.

Comment: @Zebs link broken.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet might be to draw the circle yourself, either using another UIView on top of the MKMapView, or using a MKAnnotationView within the Map View.

This blogger has done a similar thing (before iOS4 when overlays were added).
http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=65

Comment: during a map drag the UiView does not move with the map.