# Extending MKPolylines or create multiple MKPolylines?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I am writing an iOS 5 app which tracks a user's location in real-time, plotting their course on a `MKMapView`. Whenever a GPS reading is taken I would like a polyline to be drawn between the current and old locations, eventually forming a track (or breadcrumb) of where the user has travelled.

I am comfortable with using `MKPolyline` and `MKPolylineView` to draw a track, assuming that I have all the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` coordinates in advance, using code similar to below:

```
MKPolyline *route = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinates count:[self.coordinateArray count]];        
[mapView addOverlay:route];
```

However, since I am only getting the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` coordinates in real-time (as the `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` delegate method is called) I am unsure of the best way to draw the new polylines.

Can I extend the existing lines (i.e. adding to the C-based `coordinates` array - not having much C experience I am unsure how to do this) or do I need to create a new polyline between the next two coordinates (although I have heard that having too many individual polylines on the map can impact performance and memory usage...)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen the Apple sample app [Breadcrumb](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Breadcrumb/Introduction/Intro.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, see [how to update MKPolyline / MKPolylineView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171572/how-to-update-mkpolyline-mkpolylineview), especially the link to the the [Breadcrumb](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Breadcrumb/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code.  It may be a good starting point for what you need.

However, you'll see that a vital part of its `CrumbPath` object is a call to `realloc`.  So yes, you need to know how to manage C-style arrays if you want to efficiently store your arrays of points.  Yes, this is not easy.  Yes, C-style array manipulation is an invitation for memory leaks.

The Breadcrumb sample uses `realloc` to resize its array.  You can be a bit safer by allocating the memory the array uses with the `NSMutableData` type.  It is recommended as an answer to [Is it ok to use “classic” malloc()/free() in Objective-C/iPhone apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1153453/1318452).  Read the other solutions to see regular C `malloc()` and `free()` functions doing the same job.  Note that NSMutableData has a very handy `increaseLengthBy:` method.

When you understand why every C student attempts to use `sizeof()` incorrectly - and how to use it properly - you will understand C memory management.

Comment: Thanks for your reply (and pointing me towards the Breadcrumb sample code!).

Comment: The Breadcrumb sample link is broken. I have found the new link: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Breadcrumb/Introduction/Intro.html